# Image zoom slider issue in product page in Magento when using Safari

Tags: php, magento

By default, Magento creates a zoom slider and buttons when you add an image for the product. Now, the zoom function works great in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox.

However, when I try to access the website using Safari and open a product. The zoom buttons work but the slider doesn't. Usually, if you drag the slider, the image should zoom in or out but it doesn't. In fact, the slider doesn't work at all. Is this a bug? How can I fix address this problem? Please advice.

I'm not sure if this is a factor, I currently have version 6 of Safari

Answer (score 0):

i was having same problem before

and i solved with help of this article to solve in safari

i think there would be issue with pixel calculation.

just go throw [this link](http://www.aumento.io/2010/09/initial-magento-product-image-zoom-scale/)

hope this will help to you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion however, comparing the article to the current product.js in our Magento project, everything's identical. And I'm not exactly sure if it has anything to do with the image size. The zoom works if you just click on the + and - button but if you try to drag the slider, it doesn't work.